# How do I access the text within a (nested) Component?

Tags: react-native

I'm using [react-native-android-speech](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-speech) to read aloud certain parts of my app. When I run...

```
tts.speak({text: "Hi there"})
```

...I get a nice greeting,  but when I try to do...

```
tts.speak({text: myComponent})
```

...my app crashes.

Presumably I need to convert `myComponent` (which is always a bunch of nested components) into a string, like the HTML DOM's `textContent()` or jQuery's `text()`. `myComponent.valueOf()` and `myComponent.toString()` both return `[Object Object]`, which is of course not useful.

How can I access/generate this text?

Comment: Can't you call `tts` inside your nested component where the text resides?

Comment: @azium The Component that calls `tts.speak()` calls it on a number of different text-containing components. I'd have to set that up differently for each component -- it would probably just be easier to copy the text out into a string literal for each component.